# PHP - Count number of commas in string

Tags: php

How can I count the number of times a comma appears in a string such as this?

A,B,C,D

It should return "3"

Answer (score 33):

```
substr_count($my_string, ",")
```

If you wish to get all the elements between commas as an array, you can always

```
$splitted = explode(",", $my_string)
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use e.g. [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), or [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "A,B,C,";
echo (string)(count(explode(",",$str))-1);
```

[count](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

[array_explode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Comment: Why should anyone use two functions when there is a single native function that does the same thing?

Comment: thank you @mickmackusa , for your comment, but if you test it will return "3" as the question need is there any other answer return "3" ? .

Comment: I don't deny that it will work.  It is only that you are offering a technique that has no advantages over earlier answers.  I don't believe it benefits readers to learn worse ways to do something.  `substr_count()` is the most appropriate technique.  There is no compelling reason to use `explode()`, then `count()`, then subtract 1, then cast the number to a string.

Comment: I agree with you maybe the name of method you share return direct the result I can not test it as you not share example. but your option is static option that return the result it maybe you read on book , my answer made from scratch and produce the result different I reach this using code without read about it. thank you for comment really appreciate it HF.

Comment: You don't need to read any book.  You only need to read the earlier answers on the page to find the easier solution.  https://3v4l.org/MVAMI

Comment: I just mean that web applications and requirements are sometimes more complex, and it is better to learn how to get the same result or solve the problem from the beginning and do the steps that help you later to quickly understand the direct method. But technically in large web applications or problems you can't find a single method in the book to solve it if it's a unique problem or feature that you have to create. + I think onl answer return "3" is my answer and it will always return number of comma dynamic for any number not static method that what i mean. thank you