# How to implement class methods in array_map's callable

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, array-map

I am trying to create a class to handle arrays but I can't seem to get `array_map()` to work in it.

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
class test {
    public $values;

    public function adding($data) {
        $this->values = array_map($this->dash(), $data);
    }

    public function dash($item) {
        return '-' . $item . '-';
    }

}

var_dump($array);

$test = new test();
$test->adding($array);

// Expected: -1-,-2-,-3-,-4-... 
var_dump($test->values);
```

**This outputs**

`array(10) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(6) [6]=> int(7) [7]=> int(8) [8]=> int(9) [9]=> int(10) }`

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for test::dash(), called in [...]\arraytesting.php on line 11 and defined in [...]\arraytesting.php on line 15

Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '--' not found or invalid function name in [...]\arraytesting.php on line 11 NULL
```

What am I doing wrong or does this function just not work inside classes?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You are specifying `dash` as the callback in the wrong way.

This does not work:

```
$this->classarray = array_map($this->dash(), $data);
```

This does:

```
$this->classarray = array_map([$this, 'dash'], $data);
```

Read about the different forms a callback may take [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay. I got it working and thanks for you help. I was just wondering do you happen to have more article about callback and how to specify if correctly?

Comment: @Justin: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php

Comment: even statically works like      
           array_map( @[ self, 'dash' ] )

Comment: How can you pass a parameter with the dash function?

Comment: @Nielsapp you cannot directly, you must pass in a callable that will effectively bind the arguments that you want, e.g. `array_map(function($item) { return $this->dash($item, 'additional argument'); }, $data)`

Answer (score 16):

When using a class method as a callback for functions like `array_map()` and `usort()`, you have to send the callback as two-value array.  The 2nd value is always the name of the method as a string.  The 1st value is the context (class name or object)

```
// Static outside of class context
array_map( array( 'ClassName', 'methodName' ), $array );

// Static inside class context
array_map( array( __CLASS__, 'methodName' ), $array );

// Non-static outside of object context
array_map( array( $object, 'methodName' ), $array );

// Non-static inside of object context
array_map( array( $this, 'methodName' ), $array );
```

Answer (score 3):

`array_map($this->dash(), $data)` calls `$this->dash()` with 0 arguments and uses the return value as the callback function to apply to each member of the array. You want `array_map(array($this,'dash'), $data)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It must read

```
$this->classarray = array_map(array($this, 'dash'), $data);
```

The `array`-thing is the [PHP callback](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) for a object instance method. Callbacks to regular functions are defined as simple strings containing the function name (`'functionName'`), while static method calls are defined as `array('ClassName, 'methodName')` or as a string like that: `'ClassName::methodName'` (this works as of PHP 5.2.3).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was very helpful do you have happen to know of any more articles about this subject? Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) takes a *callback* as its first parameter.

And a callback to a static method is written like this :

```
array('classname', 'methodname')
```

Which means that, in your specific case, you'd use :

```
array_map(array('stripSlashesRecursive', ''), $value);
```

For more informations about *callbacks*, see this section of the PHP manual : [Pseudo-types and variables used in this documentation - callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Answer (score 1):

In case the class belongs to a different namespace, you need to use the complete namespaced class name. Below is an example using a CakePHP Utility class:

This will not work:

```
array_map(array('Inflector', 'humanize'), $some_array));
```

This will work:

```
array_map(array('Cake\Utility\Inflector', 'humanize'), $some_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map( array('Sanitize', 'stripSlashesRecursive'), $value) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

//Regular functions:
array_map('MyFunction', $array);

//static functions in a class:
array_map(array('MyClass', 'MyFunction'), $array);

//functions from an object:
array_map(array($this, 'MyFunction'), $array);

//functions from an parent class
array_map(array($this, 'parent::MyFunction'), $array);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).